# Aggregating with Mongo: events happened 2 times every day for 4 days

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a lots of events, in which I can filter for various things, however I wanted to filter only things happened X times every Y days for Z days. (eg: 2 times, everyday for 4 days)
I can group the timestamp for events in a week or day, I can even count them, but I cannot filter the subdocuments of a result...

I got a result like this:
I got the period (4days) events grouped and listed as interval, count. How can I filter them?

Thanks!

2 sample aggregated period here:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "period" : 1.43381e+009
            },
            "count" : 21,
            "intervals" : [ 
                {
                    "interval" : 1.43407e+009,
                    "count" : 5
                }, 
                {
                    "interval" : 1.43398e+009,
                    "count" : 16
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "period" : 1.43467e+009
            },
            "count" : 3,
            "intervals" : [ 
                {
                    "interval" : 1.43467e+009,
                    "count" : 3
                }
            ]
        }, 
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Can I point out the silence here is due to people not clearly understanding what you are asking here. You could edit the question to show a "small" sample of source data as well as the results you would expect from that data. Possibly also include what you have tried so far which might aid people in understanding what you want to achieve. Where you are coming from an where you want to go is the best way for people to help work out how to get a result.

Comment: It was only viewed 11 times - if the stats are good :) SO I don't think, but... :D  I have a lots of documents representing an event, with a timestamp field. I have an event named 'login'. How can I get from Mongo if a user was logging in twice every day for a week?